# ion rangeslider convert minutes to hours

Tags: rangeslider

I'm using ionrangeslider for a project and I want customize the label and legend. As you can see on my jsfiddle the legend start from 10 minutes to 360 minutes. Is there a way to convert by example 360 min into 6 hours and also the label.

Maybe using the function prettify?

Thx for your help!

```
$("#example_id").ionRangeSlider({
    min: 10,
    max: 360,
    step: 10,
    grid: true,
    grid_num: 1,
    postfix: ' mn'
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/spitfire378/reLmLpa2/

Answer (score 4):

You can create custom labels with the prettify option function (available on documentations).
Function as a value parameter which can be use to format your label as you can see below :

```
$("#example_id").ionRangeSlider({
    min: 10,
    max: 360,
    step: 10,
    grid: true,
    grid_num: 1,
    postfix: ' mn',
    prettify: function(value){
        if(value < 60){
            return value + ' mn';
        }else{
            return Math.round(value / 60) + ' h';
        }
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using prettify function:

```
function my_prettify (n) {
            var num = n;
            var hours = (num / 60);
            var rhours = Math.floor(hours);
            var minutes = (hours - rhours) * 60;
            var rminutes = Math.round(minutes);
            if(rhours<1)
                return rminutes + " min";
            else
                if(rminutes==0)
                    return rhours + " hour";
                else
                    return rhours + " hour & " + rminutes + " min";

        }

$(".js-range-slider").ionRangeSlider({
     type: "single",
     min: 0,
     max: 450,
     step: 15,
     grid: true,
     prettify: my_prettify,
 });
```